# How to update an exported Lightning Community Template

Tags: community, customer-community, lightning-community, community-builder, page-template

I have a managed package containing an exported Lightning Community Template. I would like to add a new page/ change an existing page on the template. When I try to re-export, it says that the name already exists and I cannot find a way to update the template. There is no documentation on this matter. How would I achieve this?

[This page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?err=1&id=community_builder_export_considerations.htm&type=5) states that "If you upgrade a managed template package, existing communities that are based on the upgraded template aren’t updated.". This leads me to believe that it is definitely possible to update a packaged template.

Thanks

Comment: How did you modify template, did you created community with that?

Comment: I have changed some text as well as adding a namespace to a create record form on a page. Neither have updated the template after packaging and the template lists the last modified date as the same as the created date.

Comment: I have created a community in a test org to test the package and the original community which the template was exported from

Comment: But then you just specify diffent name for template during export.

Comment: So essentially, there is no way to update a template? This means every release the admins will need to recreate the entire community and eventually after multiple releases, the template page will be crowded with different versions.

Comment: I have installed the Innovation hub by Salesforce from the app exchange and it contains multiple versions within the package so this confirms that you cannot edit template exports post export. This seems like an oversight from Salesforce.