# Editing & Repackaging a packaged Lightning Community Template

Tags: lightning-community, lightning-community-template

I have created a managed package which contains a lightning community template which was created by [exporting it from the lightning community](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_export_template.htm&type=5).

Now, I would like to make some modification to the template which was package, but there appears to be no way of updating it.

Need some guidance on how to update a lightning community template??

There is a similar question but it hasn't been answered yet. [How to update an exported Lightning Community Template](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/288604/how-to-update-an-exported-lightning-community-template)

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation currently in communities packaging. There is no way to update the whole template. You will have to again export everything as a new template.

Note if you already have a client that has installed it, you might just want to make the change in sandbox and push to pros via changesets.

For new clients you will have to build a new one.

These limitations are listed [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_export_considerations.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thanks!.. However there is a statement in the same page stating "`If you upgrade a managed template package, existing communities that are based on the upgraded template aren’t updated.`".. This is when I thought that we could update the template.

Comment: @sam There is something poorly written there or something is missing. Let me work on it and get back to you.As far as real hands on experience I have , I was not able to update the package anytime.